# MySQL Nested AVG over SUM

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table with the columns partner, post, postvariation

Now I'd like to know how many postvariations per post every partner has in average. I tried the following, however it is not working

```
SELECT partner, 
COUNT(DISTINCT post), 
COUNT(DISTINCT postvariation), 
AVG(COUNT(DISTINCT post,postvariation)) 
FROM posts 
GROUP BY partner 
ORDER BY `id` DESC;
```

Comment: Show us input and output, please

Comment: `COUNT(DISTINCT postvariation)/COUNT(DISTINCT post)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the query you're looking for:

```
SELECT P.partner
    , COUNT(DISTINCT P.post) AS nb_post
    , COUNT(DISTINCT P.postvariation) AS nb_postvariation
    , COUNT(DISTINCT P.postvariation) / COUNT(DISTINCT P.post) AS avg_postvariation
FROM posts P
GROUP BY P.partner
ORDER BY P.id DESC;
```

Here is the same query with an additional `GROUP BY` clause on the day:

```
SELECT P.partner
    , DATE_FORMAT(P.datefield, '%Y-%m-%d') AS pivot_date
    , COUNT(DISTINCT P.post) AS nb_post
    , COUNT(DISTINCT P.postvariation) AS nb_postvariation
    , COUNT(DISTINCT P.postvariation) / COUNT(DISTINCT P.post) AS avg_postvariation
FROM posts P
GROUP BY P.partner, DATE_FORMAT(P.datefield, '%Y-%m-%d')
ORDER BY P.id DESC;
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Those brackets will break the query on mysql.

Comment: how is performance if I use nb_postvariation / nb_posts AS avg_postvariation instead. Does it make any difference

Comment: @Manuel You'll not be able to use these aliases in the same `SELECT` statement.

Comment: just figured that out myself by try and error :D thx though! is it possible to group the same data as well by day (from a datetime field) to return a matrix like partnerA_posts, partnerA_avg, partnerB_posts ... to date1, date2, date3 ... . My idea is to plot a time series that shows the development of partners over time compared to each other.

Comment: @Manuel I've added a second query with the new `GROUP BY` clause, can you test it and tell me if this is the expected result?

Comment: Almost. Now I get like 10 rows per day, one for each partner. For plotting it would be much easier to have one row per day and the partners as columns. Or do you know any plotting lib which can handle this kind of data?

Comment: I put this problem in a further question, since it is somehow not just a grouping problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26039953/mysql-select-time-series-of-aggregated-data-of-several-partners-to-plot-graph

Answer (score 1):

Well you need to use division to find average.

### **Query**

```
SELECT partner, post, postvariation, (postvariation/post) as result 
FROM 
(
   SELECT partner, 
   COUNT(DISTINCT post) as post, 
   COUNT(DISTINCT postvariation) as postvariation
   FROM posts 
   GROUP BY partner 
   ORDER BY id DESC
) AS new_table
```

Comment: For the expected result, it's not necessary to have a subquery. You just have to combine both `COUNT` functions directly in the `SELECT` statement to get the average.

Comment: Well right, you already did it with simpler version so it was just another solution to the problem.

Comment: Oky, i didn't notice that my answer was visible when you submitted yours. In order to make your approach more readable, i suggest you to use aliases (good practice that really helps when starting to work with big/complex queries).

Answer (score -1):

You can try following query it should work:

### **Query**

```
SELECT COUNT(postvariations), partner, post 
FROM posts 
GROUP BY partner;
```