# MySQL select time series of aggregated data of several partners to plot graph

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking for a way to select data from mysql and return a time series of aggregated data as a flat matrix for plotting a graph. For every partner I'd like to know how many posts and postvariations he published on a day.

I have a flat table with the columns partner, postid, ... postvariationid, ... createdate (datetime). I do have several partners which I want to compare to each other e.g. partnerA, partnerB ... partnerN

I'm aggregating the counts per day per partner by

```
SELECT P.partner
    , DATE_FORMAT(P.datefield, '%Y-%m-%d') AS pivot_date
    , COUNT(DISTINCT P.postid) AS nb_post
    , COUNT(DISTINCT P.postvariationid) AS nb_postvariation
    , COUNT(DISTINCT P.postvariationid) / COUNT(DISTINCT P.postid) AS avg_postvariation
FROM posts P
GROUP BY P.partner, DATE_FORMAT(P.datefield, '%Y-%m-%d')
ORDER BY pivot_date ASC
```

DDL

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `partner` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `postid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `postvariationid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `dateupdated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uid` (`uid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Sample Data

```
INSERT INTO posts (`id`, `uid`,`partner`,`postid`, `postvariationsid`) VALUES 
(null,'1','partnerA','postA','postA_var1','2014-09-25 15:58:01'),
(null,'2','partnerA','postA','postA_var2','2014-09-25 15:58:01'),
(null,'3','partnerA','postA','postA_var3','2014-09-25 15:58:01'),
(null,'4','partnerA','postB','postB_var1','2014-09-25 15:58:01'),
(null,'5','partnerA','postB','postB_var1','2014-09-25 15:58:01'),
(null,'6','partnerA','postB','postB_var1','2014-09-25 15:58:01'),
(null,'7','partnerC','postC','postC_var1','2014-09-25 15:58:01'),
(null,'8','partnerD','postD','postD_var1','2014-09-25 15:58:01'),
(null,'9','partnerE','postE','postC_var1','2014-09-25 15:58:01'),
(null,'11','partnerA','postK','postK_var1','2014-09-24 15:58:01'),
(null,'12','partnerA','postK','postK_var2','2014-09-24 15:58:01'),
(null,'13','partnerA','postK','postK_var3','2014-09-24 15:58:01'),
(null,'14','partnerA','postL','postL_var1','2014-09-24 15:58:01'),
(null,'15','partnerA','postL','postL_var2','2014-09-24 15:58:01'),
(null,'16','partnerA','postL','postL_var3','2014-09-24 15:58:01'),
(null,'17','partnerC','postM','postM_var1','2014-09-24 15:58:01'),
(null,'18','partnerD','postN','postN_var1','2014-09-24 15:58:01'),
(null,'19','partnerE','postO','postO_var1','2014-09-24 15:58:01'),
(null,'21','partnerA','postF','postF_var1','2014-09-23 15:58:01'),
(null,'22','partnerA','postF','postF_var2','2014-09-23 15:58:01'),
(null,'23','partnerA','postF','postF_var3','2014-09-23 15:58:01'),
(null,'24','partnerA','postG','postG_var1','2014-09-23 15:58:01'),
(null,'25','partnerA','postG','postG_var1','2014-09-23 15:58:01'),
(null,'26','partnerA','postG','postG_var1','2014-09-23 15:58:01'),
(null,'27','partnerC','postH','postH_var1','2014-09-23 15:58:01'),
(null,'28','partnerD','postI','postI_var1','2014-09-23 15:58:01'),
(null,'29','partnerE','postJ','postJ_var1','2014-09-23 15:58:01');
```

This query returns me 4 rows per day. One per partner.

**How can I flatten the table that I get as output one row with columns for each partner e.g.: date_day, partnerA_nb_posts, partnerA_nb_postvariations, partnerB_nb_posts, partnerB_nb_postvariations ... and only one rows per day?**

Thx I really appreciate your expertise!

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: The resultset is already described in the question. I hope this is understandable? What you understand by DDL's?

Comment: Google's good at that

Comment: sqlfiddle is down right now, I don't have DDL's however just made a mysql structure export. I cannot supply sample data since it is sensitive (cannot publish it before publishing my master thesis)

Comment: The data doesn't have to be 'real' - just 'representative'! And I know that sqlfiddle often goes down -  but it seems to be working for me!

Comment: added. Is sqlfiddle working for you or do just I have a problem with it?

Comment: What do you use to plot the graph?

Comment: It works for me... http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7deed/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want this dynamic pivot?This will keep adding new columns if you add more partners,just dont try this in phpmyadmin,use some modern client like heidisql.

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;

SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(CASE WHEN partner= ''',
      partner,
      ''' THEN nb_post END) AS ',
      CONCAT(partner,'nb_post'),
       ',MAX(CASE WHEN partner= ''',
      partner,
      ''' THEN nb_postvariation END) AS ',
      CONCAT(partner,'nb_postvariation')
    )
   )INTO @sql
FROM  
(SELECT P.partner
    , DATE_FORMAT(P.dateupdated, "%Y-%m-%d") AS pivot_date
    , COUNT(DISTINCT P.postid) AS nb_post
    , COUNT(DISTINCT P.postvariationid) AS nb_postvariation
    , COUNT(DISTINCT P.postvariationid) / COUNT(DISTINCT P.postid) AS avg_postvariation
FROM posts P
GROUP BY P.partner, DATE_FORMAT(P.dateupdated, "%Y-%m-%d")
ORDER BY pivot_date ASC)x;

SET @sql=CONCAT('SELECT pivot_date, ',@sql,' FROM
               (SELECT P.partner
    , DATE_FORMAT(P.dateupdated, "%Y-%m-%d") AS pivot_date
    , COUNT(DISTINCT P.postid) AS nb_post
    , COUNT(DISTINCT P.postvariationid) AS nb_postvariation
    , COUNT(DISTINCT P.postvariationid) / COUNT(DISTINCT P.postid) AS avg_postvariation
FROM posts P
GROUP BY P.partner, DATE_FORMAT(P.dateupdated, "%Y-%m-%d")
ORDER BY pivot_date ASC)x
GROUP BY pivot_date');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Without the dynamic part the query would simply look like

`MAX(CASE WHEN partner=  ... THEN ) as` for each partner.We use dynamic sql so we don`t need a new case for each client.
Here are the results

[FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7deed/33)

We then simply incorporate this @sql variable with all those cases into the main corpus of the query giving the final result.

[FINAL query which gives the desired results](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7deed/34)

If you copy the result above and run it directly you have the desired results,all that mambo-jambo builds this query.

As to the insert just create a new table with fields matching the results of the query,and simply do INSERT ..INTO SELECT.Not sure why 2 values are null,might be a sqlfiddle issue.

[FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63108/1)

Or simpler get the query and do CREATE TABLE.. as SELECT..keeping the column names

[CREATE TABLE SELECT](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0646/1)

[FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7deed/15)

Comment: Is this working on shell and with an myisam db? May it be possible to export it straight to a csv file?

Comment: @Manuel Here is the query on myisam engine http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4835/1. Not sure about the shell but use heidisql put the results of the query into a table and dump that to csv,has a nice graphical interface.

Comment: ok, I love this query. It's gonna be my new favourite. However you please give me a short summery what which part of the query is doing, that I can understand it? How can I put the results of the query into a new table?

Answer (score 0):

So, you have this result set:

```
 +----------+------------+---------+------------------+-------------------+
 | partner  | pivot_date | nb_post | nb_postvariation | avg_postvariation |
 +----------+------------+---------+------------------+-------------------+
 | partnerD | 2014-09-23 |       1 |                1 |            1.0000 |
 | partnerE | 2014-09-23 |       1 |                1 |            1.0000 |
 | partnerA | 2014-09-23 |       2 |                4 |            2.0000 |
 | partnerC | 2014-09-23 |       1 |                1 |            1.0000 |
 | partnerA | 2014-09-24 |       2 |                6 |            3.0000 |
 | partnerC | 2014-09-24 |       1 |                1 |            1.0000 |
 | partnerD | 2014-09-24 |       1 |                1 |            1.0000 |
 | partnerE | 2014-09-24 |       1 |                1 |            1.0000 |
 | partnerA | 2014-09-25 |       2 |                4 |            2.0000 |
 | partnerC | 2014-09-25 |       1 |                1 |            1.0000 |
 | partnerD | 2014-09-25 |       1 |                1 |            1.0000 |
 | partnerE | 2014-09-25 |       1 |                1 |            1.0000 |
 +----------+------------+---------+------------------+-------------------+
```

What would you like instead, and what are you using to generate the graph?

Comment: I know what the result looks like. As you can read in the question How can I flatten the table that I get as output one row with columns for each partner e.g.: date_day, partnerA_nb_posts, partnerA_nb_postvariations, partnerB_nb_posts, partnerB_nb_postvariations ... and only one rows per day?

Comment: I thought of using excel. Any other tool which is more flexible is welcome.